# How to make Android gallery display a minimum amount of items?

Tags: android, layout, gallery

So I am trying regardless of screen size make an Android gallery display at least 2 items.

On large screens this isn't an issue because I have plenty of space to display several item.

For small screens I would like to be able to have a minimum amount of items displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing this:

1) Create a **layout-ldpi folder** and place the desired layout for small screens in there.

2) Check the density and change the layout at runtime:

```
density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

If it's small screens (LDPI for example), use another XML layout only displaying "a minimum amount of items".

Comment: Yeah I can get the screen size in the adapter for the gallery and get the layoutparams of the view but this seems like a bit of hack, just wondering if there is a better method.

Comment: Agreed on it feeling like a hack ;) Edited my answer with authortime sollution.

Comment: Yeah it seems ldpi-layout is probably the best way to go, just limits me to using xml though no code to make the layout.